# SQL Insert into Temp Table With Serial Number

Tags: sql

I have a simple SQL Query like:

```
Select Distinct GroupCode 
Into   #TempTable
From   MyTable
SELECT * FROM #TempTable
drop Table #TempTable
```

And its OutPut is as

[image]

Now, I also want a Serial Number Column like 1,2,3.... there in the Out put.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Since it's a temp table you could use `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Yes.. can you please help me how can I use this?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+to+use+row_number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add `row_number()`:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as id, GroupCode 
into   #TempTable
from   (select distinct GroupCode from MyTable) t;

select *
from #TempTable;

drop Table #TempTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly create the temp table and add an `IDENTITY` column for your serial numbers, like so:

```
create table #tmp(id int identity(1,1), groupcode uniqueidentifier)

insert into #tmp (groupcode)
Select Distinct GroupCode
from mytable

select * from #tmp
order by id

drop table #tmp
```

Comment: You have not defined datatype for ID column